# Dynamic SQL with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a SQL query stored in a table that contains parameter names. I need to know how to execute it properly in a stored procedure.

This is my SQL code in the procedure

```
PROCEDURE [spMassUpdateSKUs]
@SKU AS NVARCHAR(20)
,@FIELD AS NVARCHAR(50)
,@VALUE AS NVARCHAR(50)
,@RESULT as Int = Null Output
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT CODENUMBER FROM INVENTORY_MASTER WHERE CODENUMBER=@SKU)
    BEGIN   
    DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @SQLQUERY=(SELECT SQLUPDATE FROM MASS_UPDATE WHERE DROPDOWNLABEL=@FIELD)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQUERY
    END
```

and this is the sql query from the table

```
update inventory_master_flex set departmentid=@value where codenumber=@sku
```

I've tried replacing with the real parameters but that doen't work.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLQUERY,'@VALUE',@VALUE),'@SKU',@SKU)
```

Comment: When you executed this `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLQUERY,'@VALUE',@VALUE),'@SKU',@SKU)` what did the update query look like? Did it look correct or not? What do you mean it doesn't work?  **If departmentid and codenumber are strings you need single quotes around them.**

Comment: The capitalization is different.  By default, SQL Server is case-insensitive, but your table, database, or server might be configured differently.

Comment: Your values won't be quoted with your current `REPLACE` code. You should pass the parameters properly though, using [sp_executesql](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- 50 is too short for sure; you may try 1000 or different number
DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- for debug purpose
PRINT @SQLQUERY

-- params
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQUERY, N'@Value NVARCHAR(50), @sku NVARCHAR(50)`, @Value, @sku
```

REPLACE is not good in case of strings with quotes and so on which would brake the @sqlquery code.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameters in using `sp_executesql`, not `replace()`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT CODENUMBER FROM INVENTORY_MASTER WHERE CODENUMBER=@SKU)
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @SQLQUERY = (SELECT SQLUPDATE FROM MASS_UPDATE WHERE DROPDOWNLABEL = @FIELD);

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQUERY, N'@SKU VARCHAR(255), @VALUE VARCHAR(255)', @SKU = @SKU, @VALUE = @VALUE
    END;
```

I don't know what the types are.  But if one or both are strings or dates, then you would need single quotes in your implementation.  However, you are already using `sp_executesql` so go whole-hog and pass in parameters as well.